# Python BS4 - How to find all attributes in a specific class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract all the contents of the value tag in a `div`.
I am able to get the contents of the `<div class>`, but I've been unable to get the contents of the values inside of that class:

```
<div class='styled-radio'>
<input type="radio" name="variant_id" id="variant_id_105589" value="105589" 
class="js-change-quantity" data-count-on-hand="1" data-options-threshold="5" 
/>
<label for="variant_id_105589">41</label>
<input type="radio" name="variant_id" id="variant_id_105591" value="105591" 
class="js-change-quantity" data-count-on-hand="1" data-options-threshold="5" 
/>
<label for="variant_id_105591">43</label>
</div>
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: And... what is the python code you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

for example if you want all `value` of `input` tag you can do this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
sdata = """
<div class='styled-radio'>
<input type="radio" name="variant_id" id="variant_id_105589" value="105589"
class="js-change-quantity" data-count-on-hand="1" data-options-threshold="5"
/>
<label for="variant_id_105589">41</label>
<input type="radio" name="variant_id" id="variant_id_105591" value="105591"
class="js-change-quantity" data-count-on-hand="1" data-options-threshold="5"
/>
<label for="variant_id_105591">43</label>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(sdata)
mydivs = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'styled-radio'})
for div in mydivs: 
    # if you want to print a dict of all values use it
    # for children in div.findAll():
    #     print(children.attrs)

    # if you want to print a specific attr from a specific tag use it
    for children in div.findAll('input'): # find all inputs from `div`
        print(children['value']) # get `value` attrs
```

**Output**

```
105589
105591
```

**Update** 
@bobrobbob is right we can get attrs without `findChildren()` and also without `attrs` it also will work and output will be the same

Comment: you don't need children. just find the inputs and then `attrs`